# Creating an Alert tied to a Screener which only paints a square not tied to chart price

Tags: pine-script, alerts

I'd like to create an alert based on the appearance of the colored-squares painted by this section of code in the amazing TradingView screener, BEST ABCD pattern Screener - https://www.tradingview.com/v/a9oPe2pW/

plotshape(s00_bull or s00_bear ? 0 : na , title='Square 1', style=shape.square, location=location.absolute, color=s00_color, size = size.tiny, offset=-2)

(This is for the bottom line in the picture below)
plotshape (a built-in function) Plots visual shapes on the chart.

Sample chart with ABCD screener at bottom.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHsEv.jpg

I've tried the clicking on those squares and adding alerts, but none of the options "tie" an applicable value to the Square 1 that trigger the alert. They seem to be tied to PYPL chart price.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyk0R.jpg

I tried variabilizing the value in plotshape for some parameters, like color to build a long or short entry via strategy but the backtest errored on my variables.